# Can i reload ejabberd module without server restart?

Tags: ejabberd

I uploaded a modified module to server. my server has many connected users.
i don't want to restart ejabberd server for reloading modified module.

Can i reload ejabberd module without server restart?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem but found no great solution. I need to `ejabberdctl restart`  :(